# How to use multiple field search and prevent from sql injection

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a HTML form with several search parameters. On submit I use the sent values to build a query. The code looks similar to this:

```php
....
$keyword1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword1']);
$keyword2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword2']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable 
        WHERE field1 LIKE '%$keyword1%' 
        OR field2 LIKE '%$keyword2%'..."

$result = mysql_query($query);
while...etc
```

This feels like a security issue, because of the LIKE '%%' condition.
I have searched this site for answers and the solutions seem to be prepared statements. But, all examples I found use the equal sign (=) in the statement. If I use LIKE in the query, prepared statements do not help against SQL injection? Right?

Any code suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: why not? you can use prepared statement for all cases :) see it in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: Is it necessary to use these mysql* functions? Why not use PDO?

Answer (score 0):

The only extra security concern with a `LIKE` comparison is that the wildcard character itself will not be escaped.

If the possibility of the user including extra wildcard characters in their input is a concern, you could remove them using `str_replace`:

```
$keyword1 = str_replace('%','',$keyword1);
```

Whether you are using `mysqli` prepared statements or `mysqli_real_escape_string` directly should not make a difference here.